# iOS Audio/Video Live Broadcast Solution

Tags: ios, video-streaming, broadcast, broadcasting

I am developing a social app for android and iOS,
iOS and Server work has started.

Our App needs to broadcast live audio/video to end users using our app.
We have tried using setting up Servers using RED5 and WOWZA.

In iOS we got crashes, buggy frameworks from RED5 iOS SDK for broadcaster so we moved for trial version of WOWZA

After implementing WOWZA GoCoder SDK for iOS we found that its license is too much costly for me of $8000 + $2000/year maintenance :(

The midnight coder seems to be buggy from the reviews (I have not used it for broadcaster client yet)

Can anybody recommend me for good iOS SDK or some custom way to implement live broadcast streaming from my mobile camera.

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: :- Did found any solution ?

Comment: We implemented Red5 Pro later after discussing issue with their technical team, their team resolved the issues to make the SDK more stable.

Answer (score 0):

- You can use NGINX RTMP for Live streaming server https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module
- And in iOS for broadcasting you can use https://github.com/LaiFengiOS/LFLiveKit

both are free libraries